# Scanner nextLine() doesn't seem to change string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So my problem is I'm trying to make a very simple program to refresh my terrible coding skills, but I've run into a problem I don't understand. The program is supposed to take the answer "Yes" and print "yay", just to check if it worked, but it doesn't work. So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class main {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int playerTroops, computerTroops;
        String teamName, computerName = "Orcs", answer;
        Scanner listener = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Welcome to the Battle Grounds, where you are responsible for winning a war \nAre you ready? \nYes or No");
        answer = listener.nextLine();

        if (answer == "Yes")
            System.out.println("Yayy");
        else
            System.out.println("Why");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Java String comparison, you must use the .equals operator:

```
if(answer.equals("Yes"))
```

If you want to ignore case,

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
```

In Java, the operator `==` checks for reference equality. Under normal circumstances, *equal* strings don't automatically have same reference (I.E: They are different objects. This distinction is utterly important in Java).